# Find real and complex $A_{m \times n}$ such that $\operatorname{Ran} A = \operatorname{Ker} A^T$ where $\operatorname{Ran} A$ is column space of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

$\newcommand{\Ran}{\operatorname{Ran}} \newcommand{\Ker}{\operatorname{Ker}}\newcommand{\b}{\mathbf}$
If $\b y \in \Ran A$ and $\b y \in \Ker A^T$, then $\b y = A \b x$ and $A^T \b y = \b 0 $ or $A^TA \b x = \b 0$.

Therefore either $\b x = \b 0$ or $A^TA=0$. I need a $A$ such that $A^TA = 0_{m \times m}$.

For complex matrix $A$, I easily found $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -i\\i &1\end{bmatrix}$$

but I can't find a real matrix $A$.

If I expand the product, $A^TA = 0$, I get $$0= (A^TA)_{ij} = \sum^m_{k=1} \left(A^T\right)_{ik}\left(A\right)_{kj} = \sum^m_{k=1} \left(A\right)_{ki}\left(A\right)_{kj}$$
for $i = j$, $\sum^m_{k=1} \left(A\right)_{ki}\left(A\right)_{ki} = 0$ which implies $A_{ki} = 0$ for all $1\le k \le m$. Since $1\le i \le m$, therefore $A_{ki} = 0$ for all $1 \le k,i\le m$.

The matrix $$B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0 &0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$ satisfies the condition $B_{ij} = 0$ for all $1 \le i,j\le m = 2$ but $B^TB \ne 0$.

---

My question :

Is there a real matrix (non-trivial) for which $\Ran A = \Ker A^T$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the definition of matrix multiplicaton $\DeclareMathOperator{\Col}{Col} \ker(A) = \Col(A^T)^\perp$, where $A$ is a real matrix and $\Col$ denotes column space (or range in your notation).  Replacing $A$ by $A^T$ yields $\ker(A^T) = \Col(A)^\perp$.  Thus you are asking if it is possible that $\Col(A) = \Col(A)^\perp$.  Since $\Col(A) \cap \Col(A)^\perp = \{0\}$, this is impossible except for the degenerate case of $m = n = 0$ and $A$ the $0 \times 0$ zero matrix.

Comment: What does $\perp$ stands for in $\Col(A^T)^\perp$ ?

Comment: $\perp$ means [orthogonal complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement): given a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, $S^\perp = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x \cdot s = 0 \text{ for all } s \in S\}$.  So all the first sentence of my answer is saying that $Ax = 0$ means that $x$ is perpendicular to each of the rows of $A$ (which are the columns of $A^T$).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an argument for a real Euclidean space. Note that if $A \neq 0$ then $\langle A v, A v \rangle > 0$ for some $v$. Then since $\langle A^{\mathrm{t}} A v, v \rangle = \langle A v, A v \rangle > 0$ it follows that $A^{\mathrm{t}} A v \neq 0$. So $A v$ is in the range of $A$ but not in the kernel of $A^{\mathrm{t}}$.

Comment: Sorry I haven't learnt about inner products till now. Still thanks for the answer, I got the gist of your answer.